# Is it possible to find documents using incomplete words and ArangoSearch?

Tags: arangodb

For example, let's pretend my document contained the attribute "description" and the value of it was "Quick brown fox". Could ArangoSearch use the input, "Quic" and be able to find the document that contains the description, "Quick brown fox"?

As far as I know, ArangoSearch can only find matches if the token/word is completed. Is this true?

Here's some query code to show what I'm talking about. If the binding variable, `@searchInputValue`, takes the value of "Quic", it won't find the document, but if it takes the value of "Quick", it does find the document.

```
FOR document IN v_test
    SEARCH ANALYZER(
        (
            document.description IN TOKENS('@searchInputValue', 'text_en')
        )
        , 'text_en'
    ) 
    RETURN document
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FULLTEXT` function of AQL:
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Functions/Fulltext.html

However you can't write the prefix syntax directly in AQL when using Input Parameters. You have to foormat the searchInputValue, to pass:

```
Quic,+prefix:Quic
```

So you can write your query as:

```
FOR res IN FULLTEXT(v_test, "description", @searchInputValue)
RETURN res
```